# object name is not saved after scene reload

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor, unity3d-editor

I have a simple script that changes name of an object, but changed name is not remembered when I change scenes.

```
public class MyBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    private void OnValidate()
    {
        if (!this.name.Contains("_")) 
        {
            this.name = $"{this.name}_{this.GenUID()}";
        }
    }
#endif
}
```

How can I save changes made via script in `Edit-Mode`?

Comment: This may answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57124570/how-to-save-a-scriptableobject-at-runtime-after-changing-its-values

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy no, not really

Answer (score 1):

You will have to mark you object dirty so it will be saved when hitting CTRL+S

[`EditorUtility.SetDirty`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.SetDirty.html)

> You can use SetDirty when you want to modify an object without creating an undo entry, but still ensure the change is registered and not lost. If the object is part of a Scene, the Scene is marked dirty.

```
public class MyBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    private void OnValidate()
    {
        if (!this.name.Contains("_")) 
        {
            this.name = $"{this.name}_{this.GenUID()}";
            EditorUtility.SetDirty(this);
        }
    }
#endif
}
```

Also note

> If the object may be part of a Prefab instance, you additionally need to call `PrefabUtility.RecordPrefabInstancePropertyModifications` to ensure a Prefab override is created.

And if you want to also support Undo/Redo

> If you do want to support undo, you should not call `SetDirty` but rather use `Undo.RecordObject` prior to making changes to an object, since this will both mark the object as dirty (or the object's Scene if it is part of a Scene) and provide an undo entry in the editor. You should still also call `PrefabUtility.RecordPrefabInstancePropertyModifications` if the object may be part of a Prefab instance.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work, it still generates a new name after scene reload.